# Factor of two missing in simplification of Pochhammer symbol

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I am running Mathematica 14.0.0.0 and encountered this error in the simplification of the Pochhammer symbol:

`FullSimplify[Gamma[s]*Pochhammer[2-2*s,s-1]]`

returns $-2\cos(\pi s)\Gamma(2s-1)$, which is too large by a factor of two for integer $s$.

Comment: Depends. for integer s Pochhammer(2-2s) has poles For half integer Table[Gamma[s]*
   Pochhammer[2 - 2*s, s - 1], {s, -7/2, -1/2}] // Simplify  
$$\left\{\frac{\pi }{40320},-\frac{\pi }{720},\frac{\pi }{24},-\frac{\pi }{2}\right\}$$ while
Table[-2 Cos[\[Pi] s] Gamma[-1 + 2 s], {s, -7/2, -1/2}] // Quiet

{Indeterminate, Indeterminate, Indeterminate, Indeterminate}

but for {s, -7/3, -1/3}]  both forms yield numerically identical results.

Comment: I am confused, why poles? Table[Pochhammer[2 - 2*s, s - 1], {s, -3, 3}] returns {1/840, 1/60, 1/6, 1, 1, -2, 12}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is another example of a subtlety of [`FullSimplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html#15950921), which is described in the documentation under *Possible Issues*. It has also been discussed many times on this SE. Namely, `FullSimplify` can perform simplification steps which are not completely equivalent to the original expression.

In your case, the simplification is *generally* correct, but not for integer $s$.

```
expr1 = Gamma[s]*Pochhammer[2 - 2*s, s - 1];
expr2 = FullSimplify[expr1]
(* -2 Cos[π s] Gamma[-1 + 2 s] *)

expr1 == expr2 /. s -> 1/3.
(* True *)
expr1 == expr2 /. s -> 1
(* False *)
```

However, you can force `FullSimplify` to be more precise by giving it assumptions:

```
FullSimplify[expr1, s ∈ Integers]
(* Gamma[s] Pochhammer[2 - 2 s, -1 + s] *)
    
FullSimplify[expr1, s ∈ PositiveIntegers]
(* -(-1)^s Gamma[-1 + 2 s] *)
```

The last expression is now valid also for $s\in\mathbb R^+$.